# Is there any way to export windows 8.1 app?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1

Is there any way to export windows app to another windows 8.1 pc?

I have another pc where internet connection is no available.  I have downloaded some app from windows store. I want to transfer that app into another 8.1 PC.

Can I do that?

Comment: No; There isn't.

Comment: Yes, there is. there is a way to do that but you have to download the apps you want again and then you can install them on any Windows 8.1 PC. let me know if you wanna know how to do it this way.